# Deleting element and getting it's neighbours

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have got a sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6 ... n`. Now, I am given a sequence of `n` deletions - each deletion is a number which I want to delete. I need to respond to each deletion with two numbers - of a left and right neighbour of deleted number (`-1` if any doesn't exists).

E.g. I delete `2` - I respond `1 3`, then I delete `3` I respond `1 4` , I delete `6` I respond `5 -1` etc.

I want to do it fast - linear of linear-logarithmic time complexity.

What data structure should I use? I guess the key to the solution is the fact that the sequence is sorted.

Comment: Many options, you could use binary search tree or Interval tree.

Comment: How many deletions do you have? How large is the list? Are the deletions ordered somehow? Linear or linear-logarithmic time in terms of what variables? Is this a theoretical problem or a real world one?

Comment: Sounds like something you'd do with an [double-threaded binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A doubly-linked list will do fine.
We will store the links in two arrays, `prev` and `next`, to allow O(1) access for deletions.

First, for every element and two sentinels at the ends, link it to the previous and next integers:

```
init ():
    for cur := 0, 1, 2, ..., n, n+1:
        prev[cur] := cur-1
        next[cur] := cur+1
```

When you delete an element `cur`, update the links in O(1) like this:

```
remove (cur):
    print (num (prev[cur]), " ", num (next[cur]), newline)
    prev[next[cur]] := prev[cur]
    next[prev[cur]] := next[cur]
```

Here, the `num` wrapper is inserted to print `-1` for the sentinels:

```
num (cur):
    if (cur == 0) or (cur == n+1):
        return -1
    else:
        return cur
```

Here's how it works:

```
                                       prev                  next
n = 6        prev/    print       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
             /next              -------------------   -------------------
init ()                          -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
remove (2)    1 3      1 3       -1 0   1 3 4 5 6       1 3   4 5 6 7 8
remove (3)    1 4      1 4       -1 0     1 4 5 6       1 4     5 6 7 8
remove (6)    5 7      5 -1      -1 0     1 4   5       1 4     5 7   8
remove (1)    0 4      -1 4      -1       0 4   5       4       5 7   8
remove (5)    4 7      4 -1      -1       0     4       4       7     8
remove (4)    0 7      -1 -1     -1             0       7             8
```

Above, the portions not used anymore are blanked out for clarity.
The respective elements of the arrays still store the values printed above them, but we no longer access them.

As Jim Mischel rightly noted (thanks!), storing the list in two arrays instead of dynamically allocating the storage is crucial to make this O(1) per deletion.

Comment: But finding the element to delete is O(n)

Comment: @JimMischel Not if the two arrays are used instead of dynamic storage. Thanks, I'll add that, and drop the "dynamic storage" part.

Comment: @JimMischel Expanded the answer with how exactly it can be O(1).

Comment: I don't see how making arrays of links helps. Deleting in a linked list is trivially O(1). But finding the item to delete is O(n): you have to start at the head of the list and move forward to find the item.

Comment: @JimMischel The requirement is to delete a certain number, not an element in some position (number 10, not 10-th of the remaining elements). So if we index the arrays by these numbers, we get to the required item in O(1) too.

Comment: Either there's something lacking in your explanation, or I'm just thick. How do you find the number 10 in that list in O(1)? You certainly can't do it with just an array. Can you provide more detail in your answer? Or an implementation?

Comment: @JimMischel Instead of allocating separate storage for each node on the heap, we store two arrays of "pointers". But the pointers are actually integers, since with such storage, the locations in memory are given by the positions in the array. The number `10` has its neighbors conveniently stored at `prev[10]` and `next[10]`. A pseudocode implementation is included in the answer: `remove (cur)` removes the number `cur` from the list. (Let's move this to chat if I still wasn't clear.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary search tree. Deleting from it is logarithmic. If you want to remove n elements and the number of total elements is m, then the complexity of removing n elements from it will be

**nlogm**